# How to get list names of week days?

Tags: momentjs

I'm using momentjs and I would like to return the all the names of the past 7 days. I know that I can get the number using:

```
moment().isoWeekday();
```

how can I get a list of names of the past 7 days from today? eg:

```
tuesday, monday, sunday, saturday, friday, thursday, wednesday
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```js
let resultDates = []; // array to hold day names
const current = moment(); // current date
let n = 7; // days to go back
while (n > 0) {
  resultDates.push(current.format("dddd")) // get day n and push it to array
  current.subtract(1, "day") // subtract a day
  n--;
}

console.log(resultDates);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```

The first element of the array is today, the last element would be 7 days ago.